# How can obtain the value of erc20 token in transaction?

Tags: erc-20, parity

i want to get the token's transferring value like this:
https://etherscan.io/address/0x27054b13b1b798b345b591a4d22e6562d47ea75a#tokentxns

How can obtain the value of erc20 token in transaction?
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x4d2705650c17cec7703ea1d44c846fa41029b400c742bec2251c95e9bebfd037
Where and how can i get the value : "1,011.1323"

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about its USD value?

Comment: about erc token value

Comment: It shows the value to the right of "Tokens Transfered:" 1,011.1323 ($41.64) AST

Comment: yes, but can i read this data in web3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you can read the "data" field in transaction receipt.

1. Fetch transaction receipt by ethGetTransactionReceipt(txHash)
2. Remove prefix 0x from the string.
3. Use FunctionReturnDecoder or similar to decode value from the string to the BigInteger.

Result value should be the token's transfer value